# Сохранить обьект строки для дальнейшего изменения ее атрибутов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток!
Скрипт должен скрыть строки таблицы с нулевыми остатками,
остальное записать в словарь и сравнить цены (в таблице может
быть несколько одинаковых позиций товара с разной ценой).
То, что в этом словаре, нужно выделить цветом (построчно).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id='thunder-button']").click(function() {
    var bestOfferDict = {}
    $(".hide-tr-class").each(function() {
      var nonZeroFound = false;
      var brand = (this).getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerText;
      var number = (this).getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerText;
      var price = (this).getElementsByTagName('td')[5].innerText;
      var rowId = $(this);
      $(this).find("td.thunder").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().trim() != '0') {
          nonZeroFound = true;
          if (bestOfferDict[brand + ' ' + number]) {
            if (price < bestOfferDict[brand + ' ' + number].price) {
              bestOfferDict[brand + ' ' + number] = {
                'price': price,
                'rowId': rowId
              };
            }
          } else {
            bestOfferDict[brand + ' ' + number] = {
              'price': price,
              'rowId': rowId
            };
          }
        }
      });
      if (!nonZeroFound) {
        $(this).hide("slow");
      }
    });
    for (item in bestOfferDict) {
      item.rowId.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: green;');
    }
  })
})
```

Делает все, кроме выделения цветом. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rowId` - jQuery объект, а не DOMElement...

[$().css](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
bestOfferDict[item].rowId.css('background-color', 'green');
```

Или [$().get](https://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
bestOfferDict[item].rowId.get(0).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но в консоли - ошибка
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
или
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: а про setAttribute такой ошибки не было?

Comment: да, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
а не может быть проблема в var rowId = $(this);? пробую ставить console.log($(this)); сразу за var rowId = $(this); - сыплет в консоль обьектами, т.е. что-то в переменную-таки записывается...

Comment: спасибо за наводку, @vp_arth
немного поправил и всё встало на места!